# How to sum and to mean one DataFrame to create another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

After creating DataFrame with some duplicated cell values in the column **Name**:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Will','John','John','John','Alex'],
                   'Payment':  [15, 10, 10, 10, 15],
                   'Duration':    [30, 15, 15, 15, 20]})
```

[image]

I would like to proceed by creating another DataFrame where the duplicated values in **Name** column are consolidated leaving no duplicates. At the same time I want 
to sum the payments values John made. I proceed with:

```
df_sum = df.groupby('Name', axis=0).sum().reset_index()
```

[image]

But since `df.groupby('Name', axis=0).sum()` command applies the sum function to every column in DataFrame the **Duration** (of the visit in minutes) column is processed as well. Instead I would like to get an average values for the **Duration** column. So I would need to use `mean()` method, like so:

```
df_mean = df.groupby('Name', axis=0).mean().reset_index()
```

[image]

But with `mean()` function the column **Payment** is now showing the average payment values John made and not the sum of all the payments.

How to create a DataFrame where Duration values show the average values while the Payment values show the sum?

Comment: Please don't use embedded images; use text instead.  Images can't be copied and pasted into a console, which means you're asking anyone who wants to match your example to type it in manually.  (See [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/487339) for more.)

Comment: @DSM although to be fair - their very first code block has the code to create the initial DataFrame :) (as well as the commands issued to create the results...)

Comment: @NinjaPuppy: that's only one of the many reasons not to embed images (see the Meta post I linked, e.g.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can apply different functions to different columns with groupby.agg:

```
df.groupby('Name').agg({'Duration': 'mean', 'Payment': 'sum'})
Out: 
      Payment  Duration
Name                   
Alex       15        20
John       30        15
Will       15        30
```

Comment: Great answer. A less elegant approach would be to split the dataframe, apply the two functions and then combine them together: pd.concat([df.loc[:,['Duration','Name']].groupby('Name').mean(),df.loc[:,['Payment','Name']].groupby('Name').sum()], axis=1)